# creating a list from strings python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was assigned to write a program that accepts strings as input from the user and turns them into a list containing those strings. The function works, until the user inputs an empty string (`""`). If the user inputs `""` then the function should print the list of the strings so far.
I wrote the code but every time I run it I only get empty lists and I don't know how to fix it, as it should work as planned.
Can someone here give me a clue or tell me what the problem could be?

Here is my code:

```
def string_from_user():
    string_from_user = input("enter1")
    while string_from_user != "":
        string_from_user = input("enter again")
        list1 = [string_from_user]
    if string_from_user != "":
        list1.append(string_from_user)
    else:
        print(list1)
    print(list1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This code runs forever, as you didn't specify that it needed to end when the list is outputted.

```
def strings_list():
    list1 = []                                  # initialises list1 as a list

    while True:                                 # repeats forever
        string_from_user = input("Input Word")  # takes input of string

        if not string_from_user:                # if string is empty
            for item in list1:                  # prints list line at a time
                print(item)
        else:
            list1.append(string_from_user)          # adds string to end of list
```

A couple of your mistakes were using the same name for the function as a variable `string_from_user()` and `string_from_user`

Also `list1 = [string_from_user]` reset the list to just the input on every loop

Comment: You are appending the input string before the empty string validation, this will add an empty string to the list, you should validate the string before appending to the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def string_from_user():
  string_from_user = input("Please input a string: ")
  list1 = [string_from_user]
  while string_from_user != "":
    string_from_user = input("Input another string or input \"\" (emptystring) to output a list of your inputed strings:")
    list1.append(string_from_user)
  print(list1)

string_from_user()
```

Test it [here](https://repl.it/E7x4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You set `list1` equal to `[string_from_user]`, or the empty string.

Instead, you just want to create the list at the beginning, then append to it as you go.

```
def string_from_user():
    list1 = []
    while string_from_user != "":
        string_from_user = input("enter again")
        list1.append(string_from_user)
    return list1
```

How this works:

1. The `list`, `list1` is initialized.
2. Inside of the while loop, it will continue asking the user for strings until the user enters an empty string.
3. If they do, the while loop will end, and it will return `list1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def string_from_user():
    st = input()
    ret = []
    while st:
        ret.append(st)
        st = input()
    return ret
```

There's no need to check whether `st` is equal to empty string *explicitly* as any empty string is *falsy*, so only the `st` variable can be used as the condition.

Comment: The user is using Python3

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
def displayUserInput():
    user_input = None
    user_input_list = []
    while user_input != "":
        user_input = raw_input("Enter the list element ?")
        if user_input:
            user_input_list.append(user_input)
    return user_input_list
```

Answer (score -1):

Your are trying to compare string_from_user with "". This is an empty string. To compare correctly you should scape your string or use simple aspas, like '""' or \"""\"

```
def string_from_user():
    list1 = []
    string_from_user = input("enter1: ")
    while string_from_user != '""':
        if string_from_user != '""':
            list1.append(string_from_user)
        string_from_user = input("enter again: ")
    print('list:', list1)
```